# Why can Azure DevOps no longer find my file in $(Build.BinariesDirectory)?

Tags: azure-devops

Sometime in the past 2-3 hours, my builds have started failing on this step:

```
  - script: $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/tools/GitVersion.CommandLine/tools/GitVersion.exe /output buildserver /nofetch
```

..with the error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
```

I'm assuming that it can't find the script specified in the task - is this right, and if so how can I find its new location?

Comment: Are you hosting your own build agents? If yes, RDC/SSH in and investigate. If no, add some tasks to the build that run scripts to ls/Get-ChildItem on directories where the files should/could be.

Comment: Are you manually putting that EXE in that location? If no, I wouldn't expect to find it there. From the docs: `Build.BinariesDirectory: "The local path on the agent you can use as an output folder for compiled binaries."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Microsoft-hosted agents:**
You could directly use the `“GitVersion.exe /output buildserver /nofetch”`
In this way, you can avoid entering the wrong path.
[use gitversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zryt.jpg)

**For Self-hosted agents:**
You could run the `“WHERE /R c:\ gitversion.exe”` script  in “command line task” to get the specific path.
And then you can modify your script according to the obtained path.
For example:
[find gitversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWsB6.jpg)

By the way, if you couldn’t find file, please check the version of the GitVersion.

According to the [Release Note](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/releases): “Chocolatey: executable missing in GitVersion.Portable 5.3.0” ,this could cause the “Gitversion.exe” missing.
You could upgrade the **GitVersion to 5.3.1**.

Comment: Yep, your last paragraph was exactly right! As a temporary fix we've forced the version to 5.2.4 until our internal NuGet feed catches up with the latest version. Here's the GitHub issue: https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/issues/2252